# How to write if-else statement if the user input is matched or unmatched with the record in text file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I currently have a text file called `student.txt` and there are some records in the text file.
The format of the records are `StudentID|Name|ContactNumber|EmailAddress` and the records are as follows:

```
21PMR07222|Steven|011-1234567|steven@yahoo.com
21PMR07123|John|012-3456789|john@yahoo.com
21PMR07221|Amy|017-4567890|amy@gmail.com
```

How to put the following code into `if-else` statement where if the student ID entered by user is matched with the student ID in the text file, the details of the student will be displayed, else error message `"The student ID does not exist. Please enter again."` will be displayed.

```
awk -F'|' -v id="$studentID" '$1 == id { printf "Name: %s\nContact Number: %s\nEmail Address: %s\n", $2, $3, $4 }' < student.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea:

```
awk -F'|' -v id="$studentID" '
$1 == id { found=1; printf "Name: %s\nContact Number: %s\nEmail Address: %s\n", $2, $3, $4 }
END      { if (found==0) printf "The student ID does not exist. Please enter again." }
' student.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- this `awk` code is not going to prompt the user for a new `studentID`
- the parent code will need to be able to capture and parse the `awk` output to determine if it should ask the user a new question; alternatively ...
- the `awk` code could return a non-0 status that the parent code could use to determine if the user should be prompted to enter a new `studentID`

Have `awk` return a non-0 status code that the parent code can use for follow-on processing:

```
awk -F'|' -v id="$studentID" '
$1 == id { found=1
           printf "Name: %s\nContact Number: %s\nEmail Address: %s\n", $2, $3, $4
         }
END      { if (found==0) {
              printf "The student ID does not exist. Please enter again." 
              exit 1
           }
         }
' student.txt

awk_exit_status=$?
```

The default exit status of an `awk` script is 0 (ie, no issues).  The `END{...}` block will generate an exit status of `1` if `found==0`.

The `bash` variable `awk_exit_status` will contain either a `0` (`Name: ... Contact Number ... Email Address ...`) or `1` (`The student ID does not exist`) which the parent `bash` script can then use to determine how to proceed.

Comment: Is it that I need to write `while [[ awk_exit_status==1 ]] do (let user to reenter the student ID)` below the code?

Comment: would need to see more of your code as there are many options, eg, `while true; do <ask_question>; <run_awk>; awk_status=$?; [[ "${awk_status}" == 0 ]] && break; done`; if you have issues with your looping construct I'd suggest asking a new question